# At a party of only 2 people, will these 2 people actually know each other? - Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I am aware of the proof - Given that there are $n$ people in a party $\left(~\mbox{where}\ n \geq 2~\right)$, there are $2$ people who know the same number of people.

*Assuming:*

1. *knowledge is mutual so if A knows B, B also knows A*
2. *knowing oneself is not counted*

.
.

Where the proof goes as follows:

- Case 1: There is someone who knows everyone $\left(n-1\right)$ people in the party so range is $\bf\left[1,n - 1\right]$.
- Case 2: There is nobody who knows everyone in the party so range is $\bf\left[0,n - 2\right]$.

In either case, the **pigeonhole principle** says there are two that match.

.
.

My question is: In the specific scenario where the number of people (n) is equals to 2 then, according to this proof it shows that these 2 people who are the only ones at the party both know the **same number** of people which is 1. From here, can I conclude that these 2 people actually know each other?

**So not only do these 2 people know the same number of people BUT is it correct to say that they also know the SAME people (assuming people are distinguishable) ?**

If this is the case, it is just really puzzling to me that the **pigeonhole principle** is able to come to a conclusion by itself almost magically that 2 people actually know each other..

Comment: It's possible that the 2 people know 0 others (hence don't know each other).

Comment: @peterwhy A person cannot know themself / knowing oneself is not counted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem doesn't assert that they know each other. It states that they know the same number of people. If they know each other, this number is 1; if they don't know each other, it's 0.

Comment: @rustlecho For any given $n$, both cases of the proof are possible. When $n=2$, if the two people know each other, then case 1 applies, and if they don't know each other, then case 2 applies.